# values of lastprivate variable not available outside parallel region in OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I am using OpenMP and Visual Studio 2008 for my project. I have a parallel for loop in my function and I want to update a variable that is defined outside this parallel-for in the parallel region. Since I want the values to be available after the parallel region, I have declared the variable in lastprivate() clause. But after the execution of the parallel region, I am not getting any values for the variable. The following is my code:

```
vector<string> resultParamsNames;
int count = 0;
        #pragma omp parallel for private(s,s_fa,measR1Value,c) firstprivate(count,paramNamesSet) lastprivate(resultParamsNames, count)
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        fitModel(model, t, c, inputFunctions, at, dt, resultParams, resultParamsNames, fittedCurve);
    }
```

Here, 'resultParamsNames' is the variable that I am updating in the parallel region. How can I get the values for this variable outside the parallel region?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: Also the variable 'count' value is also not available outside the region. For privacy reasons, I cannot post the whole code.

Comment: Even if you can't post the private code you should try and make a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).  Meanwhile you should read up on [first and last private](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#LastprivateClause).  I don't think you can do what you want to do with them.  You may need a reduction and/or atomic/critical clauses.